# User field names?

Tags: users

The online documentation states:

> Each user has an email address and username by default, and optional fields for a name, photo, and password.

Excuse the dumb question, but where do I find the what the names of those fields are? I feel like I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is from Twig, it would be:

```
{{ user.firstName }}
{{ user.lastName }}
{{ user.photo }}
```

I'm 90% sure that `user.password` isn't exposed to Twig by default (for security reasons), but there are ways around that if you really need to expose the password hash to a template.

Note that first and last names are string, but the photo is an instance of  `craft\elements\Asset`.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. Is there a reference somewhere would I could have found this out myself without posting a question? Appreciate any direction. I seem to have this problem often with Craft.

Comment: firstName and lastName are properties on the User element: https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/users.html#firstname and https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/users.html#lastname. photo is a bit of an edge case, so you'd have to go to the class reference for that https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-elements-user.html#method-getphoto